# Отправка magic-пакета из Windows в Debian (WakeOnLan)

Tags: windows, debian

Настроил wakeonlan на домашнем сервере с debian 10, но никак не могу найти, как с windows послать Magic-пакет. Помогите, пожалуйста. Гугл не помог *или я очень плохо искал((*

Comment: причем на лине можно написать wakeonlan [ip-адрес], а с виндой как-то надо потанцевать, если я правильно понял....

Comment: Вроде [решение](https://www.pdq.com/blog/wake-on-lan-wol-magic-packet-powershell/) есть с помощью Powershell

Comment: http://white55.narod.ru/wol.html

Answer (score 1):

Поставь програмку вроде https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html или https://pypi.org/project/wakeonlan/ посылай пакет с неё. Можно собрать линуксовую програмку на виндовс (cygwin) или написать свою.